# upgrade rudder 4.3 to 6.0

Tags: upgrade, rudder

i  tried to upgrade rudder 4.3 to 5.0 but nothing works.And i try upgrade rudder 4.3 to 6.0 but nothing to works. the rest does not work. 
My OS server is Centos 6.10

can you help me please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnQAN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tizDI.png)

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://docs.rudder.io/reference/5.0/installation/operating_systems.html#server-supported-os), centOS 6 isn't supported anymore for rudder 5 (nor 6). You will need to use CentOS 7 with these versions of rudder.